# console.log value from random array give me variable is not defined . JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the value of the array, but gives me the error rand ( my variable) is not define.
The array is working fine and adding the values to a class.. So i cant really understand why its not working.

This is my function.

```
     function AddEvent(){ 
            var AddEvent = "add"; 
            var addClass= document.getElementsByClassName(AddEvent); 
            addClass=addClass[addClass.length-1]; 
            addClass.addEventListener("click", addDiceEvent, true); 
            var diceArray = Array=[ 
            "one", 
            "two", 
            "three", 
            "four", 
            "five", 
            "six"]; 
            console.log("when set",addClass);
            function addDiceEvent() { 
                var rand = diceArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * diceArray.length)]; 
                dicesides_func.call(addClass,rand); 
               }      


    }    
// Console.log(rand) gives the error # Uncaught ReferenceError: rand is not defined #
AddEvent();
```

Comment: If you wish to call `dicesides_func` function with two arguments `addClass` and `rand`, simply use `dicesides_func(addClass, rand)`.

Comment: Where exactly do you call the `console.log`?

Comment: @Bergi its commented before AddEvent(); but it really dont mater where it is, gives me the same error

Comment: Then it's obvious that `rand` is `undefined`, neither was the event handler created (in scope of `AddEvent`, nor was it attached, nor was it fired, nor is `rand` available from that outer scope. Put the log statement direclty after `var rand = …`, and click your button then.